# why is my header("Location: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']"); PHP function not working?

Tags: php, url, redirect, http-referer

It works when I input

```
header("Location: http://www.google.com");
```

but it doesn't work when I have

```
header("Location: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']");
```

I want to redirect the page to whatever page it came from.

Comment: Not all browsers send a referer, and some that do, send bogus data. As well, you can't use quotes on an array key within a double-quoted string like that. try `header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");` instead.

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`?

Comment: what is the output of this string:
echo "Location: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']";
?

Comment: @MarcB is right.  You can verify this behavior by firing up Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and taking a look at the headers you get back.  I always concat variables like this rather than putting them inline, so code is easy to read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try it: :)

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
else
   echo "No referrer.";
```

However, for determining which page user came from, I'd rather use session variable, which gets reset at every page:

```
session_start();
echo "Previous page:", $_SESSION['loc'];
$_SESSION['loc']=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

ps: This only works for local pages, you cannot track other websites.

Answer (score 4):

You might try:

```
header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
```

I've had problems with variable expressions which contain quotes in strings without braces.

You also need to look out for `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` simply not being set. Some user agents don't set it, some privary tools mask it, and you need to handle people coming to your page without a referrer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple solution. 
check and see what $_server['http_referer'] is giving you and if its set then you can redirect and if not put a fall back url something like :

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != ""){
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}else{
$url = "YOUR INDEX PAGE OR SOMETHING";
}

header("Location: ".$url);
```

Answer (score 2):

> This is a browser feature, and any polite browser will send the
>   correct header (although various 'security' tools will override this
>   with a fake referer).

It's browser specific so not every browser/security software combination will send it to the server. You're better off setting a session variable on each page load to determine which page the user came from (or something similar with a bit more logic)

Comment: so make a session of the current url on each page?

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Location: $_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]");
```

Without the single quotes. This is the fastest way to access and concatenate array values without extra concatenating code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    header("Location:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the mistakes that occure sometimes is, that NO OUTPUT must happen before header('Location: ' ....)

This is not working (shows the output, but doesn't redirect):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $cleaned_url = preg_replace('/[^a-z ]+/i', '', strtolower($referer));
    $pattern = '/troester/';
    $res = preg_match($pattern, $cleaned_url);
    echo $res; // <--- OUTPUT COMES HERE
    if ($res == true) header("Location: {$referer}");
}
```

This is working (does redirect properly):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $cleaned_url = preg_replace('/[^a-z ]+/i', '', strtolower($referer));
    $pattern = '/troester/';
    $res = preg_match($pattern, $cleaned_url);
    //echo $res; // <--- NO OUTPUT COMES HERE
    if ($res == true) header("Location: {$referer}");
}
```

This is also working, but doesn't make sense ():

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $cleaned_url = preg_replace('/[^a-z ]+/i', '', strtolower($referer));
    $pattern = '/troester/';
    $res = preg_match($pattern, $cleaned_url);
    if ($res == true) header("Location: {$referer}");
    echo $res; // <--- OUTPUT COMES HERE, AFTER header('Location: ' ....)
}
```

(For better understandig, hope this may help)